Identical systems different desktops - how to change
I have two more or less identical systems running Ubuntu 20.04. One has nice colorful graphic desktop icons and the other clunky black and white icons. I cannot find any reference to changing the clunky icons to the colorful versions.
Colorful:

Clunky:


Looks like you've selected the High Contrast theme. Try another one.
